# ¿Cómo devolver puntero de char's en C?

Tags: c

Estoy intentando de devolver un puntero de char, pero me arroja el siguiente error:

`assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion] -> auxcandidate = alpha[pos]`.

Este es mi código:

```
char* getkey(int minimo, int maximo, int alphalen, int index, char alpha[]); 

int main()  {  
   int minimo = 2;
   int maximo = 2;
   char *alpha = "abc";
   int alphalen = strlen(alpha);
   char *candidata;

   printf("La candidata es: ");
   candidata = getkey(minimo, maximo, alphalen, 5, alpha);

   return 0; 
}

char* getkey (int minimo, int maximo, int alphalen, int index, char alpha[]){
    int cociente, residuo, cont;
    int i = 0;
    char cand[maximo+1];
    char* auxcandidate;

    while (index != 0)
    {
        cociente = index / alphalen;
        residuo = index%alphalen;
        cand[i] = residuo;
        index = cociente;
        i+=1;
    }

    for (cont=i-1; cont>=0; cont--)  
    {   
        int pos = cand [cont];
        auxcandidate = alpha[pos];      
    }

   return auxcandidate;
}
```

Puede alguien explicar este error? Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Estás asignando un entero `alpha[pos]` a un puntero `auxcandidate` lo correcto sería asignar una dirección de memoria que es lo que se espera de un puntero:

```
auxcandidate = &alpha[pos];
```

Aquí te dejo un [link](http://c.conclase.net/curso/?cap=012b) que quizás te sirva para entender un poco mas de arrays y punteros y sus correspondencias o equivalencias.

*Nota: el mensaje de error te dice `integer` porque `char` se traduce a un entero*

Answer (score 1):

Lo que pasa es que en esta linea `auxcandidate = alpha[pos];` estas diciendo que el puntero `auxcandidate` que es una dirección le asignas un `char`, solo agrega el operador `&`, así `auxcandidate = &alpha[pos];`.

Comment: al agregar & (auxcandidate = &alpha[pos];) sólo me devuelve el último char recorrido por for.

Comment: @user5672720 ese es el error, no sabemos que estás queriendo hacer con tu lógica, si no estas obteniendo lo que quieres deberías reveer tu código y formular una nueva pregunta concreta con esa duda y la salida esperada que no puedes obtener, pero es correcto lo que te respondemos, no puedes asignar un entero que es lo que estás resolviendo con `alpha[pos]` a un puntero que lo que espera es una dirección de memoria no un valor.

Comment: Lo que hace la función "getkey" (while) es cambiar la base y lo almacena en un array de char (cand[]), y con el 'for' trato de extraer esos valores para devolver en cadenas. Por ejemplo que la función getkey retorno 'bc'.

Comment: En C no puedes regresar un conjunto de caracteres 'bc', lo que se hace es regresar un puntero como ya lo hace tu función. Cuando tu función haga `return` en  `candidata = getkey(minimo, maximo, alphalen, 5, alpha);` `cantidata` apuntara a la primera posicion de 'bc' es decir `b`, con este enfoque además de tener el puntero debes de saber el tamaño de lo que apunta para no acceder a memoria que no es propia del puntero, para tu caso el tamaño de lo que regresas esta en la variable `i`

Comment: Puedes mandar `i` por referencia a tu función y así saber `i` al finalizar tu función e imprimir el resultado:

En la función agrega que reciba `i`, así:
 `char* getkey (int minimo, int maximo, int alphalen, int index, char alpha[], int* i) `

Llama a la función la función así: no olvides declarar `i`
`int i = 0`
` candidata = getkey(minimo, maximo, alphalen, 5, alpha, &i);`

Ya con el tamaño puedes iterar el puntero o imprimirlo:
`printf (candidata %.*s\n", i, candidata);`

Comment: Hice los cambios con lo que me dijo, pero me arroja el error en la funcion 'getkey': ‘i’ redeclared as different kind of symbol  int i = 0;

Comment: Quita la declaración de `i` dentro de la función